# How to avoid such of nested if statment

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using the following code and I want to try to avoid this such of nested if
there is a way to better write this code in java-script?I must use all the if ...but there is a way to better write it...

...

```
} else if (NotImplementedError) {

        var oDeImpl = this._oIn.getMReturnValue(sMethod);

        if (s.getEnv("debMod")) {
            that._error("Method: " + sMethod + " not implemented" );
        } else {
            //Check if  was provided
            if (typeof oDeImpl !== 'undefined') {
                vValue = oDeImpl.def;

                if (oDefImpl.type === "object") {
                    vVal = jQuery.extend({}, vVal);
                }

                impl[sMet] = function() {
                    return vVal;
                };
            } else {
                console.error("Method: " + sMethod + " not implemented" );
                return Q();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: not a post belong here. should move to codereview.

Comment: I think this code is fine and no need to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.getEnv("debMod")` possible to get out of `if` with `NotImplementedError`

```js
//somewhere above main if statement
var isDebug = s.getEnv("debMod");


} else if (NotImplementedError && !isDebug) {

    var oDeImpl = this._oIn.getMReturnValue(sMethod);
    
    if (typeof oDeImpl !== 'undefined') {
        vValue = oDeImpl.def;
        
        if (oDefImpl.type === "object") {
            vVal = jQuery.extend({}, vVal);
        }
        
        impl[sMet] = function() {
            return vVal;
        };
    } else {
        console.error("Method: " + sMethod + " not implemented" );
        return Q();
    }
}
else if (isDebug) {
    that._error("Method: " + sMethod + " not implemented" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on programmer skill to do that. but there's some ways to do that so.

ie. you can use multiple conditions in one if and relate them with &&(AND)/||(OR).

or use `(Condition)? //if true : //if false` syntax for little conditions and so...